# How do I download and launch a JNLP file in CentOS?

Tags: centos, java, download, cluster

I'm using Amazon's GPU cluster to experiment with some HPC java code on CentOS.

The Java application is in JNLP format and has a GUI.

I've followed Amazon's [getting started video](http://www.youtube.com/embed/YfCgK1bmCjw), but I'm not sure how to use a web browser or otherwise download the file.

Secondly I'm not sure how to launch this file since it requires a GUI.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Launch it with javaws (java webstart),

e.g `javaws ~/Downloads/ContestAppletProd.jnlp`

Comment: +1, thanks.  I'm sure I don't run this in SSH.. do you have any tips on where I run this?

Comment: @makerofthings7 you run this on your computer, not on the server side, you need to have java installed on your local machine

Comment: there's no javaws anymore in 8